# Capture names containing --but not ending-- in dashes

Tags: parsing, flex-lexer

I am trying to **capture names** (not starting with a number) **which could contain dashes**, such as `hello-world`. My problem is that I also have rules for single dashes and symbols which conflict with it:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]+     { /* capture "hello-world" */ }
"-"                       { return '-'; }
">"                       { return '>'; }
```

When the lexer reads `hello-world->` the previous rules yield `hello-world-` and `>`, whereas I expected `hello-world`, `-` and `>` to be captured individually. To solve it I fixed it this way:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+     { /* ensure final dash is never included at the end */ }
```

That works, except for single-letter words, so finally I implemented this:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+     { /* ensure final dash is never included at the end */ }
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*                  { /* capture possible single letter words */ }
```

**Question**: Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+
> [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*
> ```

Note that, as you said, the first rule already covers everything that's not a single letter. So the second rule only has to match single letters and can be shortened to just `[A-Za-z]`:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+
[A-Za-z]
```

Now the second rule is a mere prefix of the first, so we can combine this into a single rule by making the part after the first letter optional:

```
[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+)?
```

The `+` on the last bit is unnecessary because everything except the last character can as well be matched by the middle part, so the simplest version is:

```
[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?
```